# How to create a contacts list

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter and just following some basic tutorials, however I have been following this: https://hackernoon.com/flutter-iii-lists-and-items-6bfa7348ab1b and I can't seem to get the code to run. Forgive the formatting, still getting used to forum.

```
      import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
      import 'contact_data.dart';

      class ContactsPage extends StatelessWidget {

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
         title: new Text("Contacts"),
      ),
      body: new ContactList(kContacts)
    );
  }

}


     class ContactList extends StatelessWidget {

   final List<Contact> _contacts;

   ContactList(this._contacts);

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return new ListItem(
       type: MaterialListType.twoLine,
       padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
       children: _buildContactList()
    );
 }

 List<_ContactListItem> _buildContactList() {
   return _contacts.map((contact) => new _ContactListItem(contact))
     .toList();
  }

}

class _ContactListItem extends ListItem {

  _ContactListItem(Contact contact) :
       super(
         title : new Text(contact.fullName),
         subtitle: new Text(contact.email),
          leading: new CircleAvatar(
          child: new Text(contact.fullName[0])
        )
     );

}
```

This is the contacts_data page I want to import information from to the ContactsPage:

```
class Contact {
  final String fullName;
   final String email;

   const Contact({this.fullName, this.email});
}


const kContacts = const <Contact>[
  const Contact(
  fullName: 'Romain Hoogmoed',
  email:'romain.hoogmoed@example.com'
  ),
   const Contact(
      fullName: 'Emilie Olsen',
      email:'emilie.olsen@example.com'
  ),
  const Contact(
       fullName: 'Téo Lefevre',
      email:'téo.lefevre@example.com'
   ),
  const Contact(
      fullName: 'Nicole Cruz',
      email:'nicole.cruz@example.com'
  ),
  const Contact(
      fullName: 'Ramna Peixoto',
      email:'ramna.peixoto@example.com'
  ),
  const Contact(
      fullName: 'Jose Ortiz',
      email:'jose.ortiz@example.com'
  ),
  const Contact(
     fullName: 'Alma Christensen',
     email:'alma.christensen@example.com'
  ),
  const Contact(
     fullName: 'Sergio Hill',
     email:'sergio.hill@example.com'
  ),
  const Contact(
     fullName: 'Malo Gonzalez',
     email:'malo.gonzalez@example.com'
 ),
 const Contact(
     fullName: 'Miguel Owens',
     email:'miguel.owens@example.com'
 ),
  const Contact(
     fullName: 'Lilou Dumont',
     email:'lilou.dumont@example.com'
 ),
  const Contact(
     fullName: 'Ashley Stewart',
     email:'ashley.stewart@example.com'
  ),
  const Contact(
       fullName: 'Roman Zhang',
      email:'roman.zhang@example.com'
 ),
  const Contact(
     fullName: 'Ryan Roberts',
     email:'ryan.roberts@example.com'
 ),
 const Contact(
     fullName: 'Sadie Thomas',
     email:'sadie.thomas@example.com'
 ),
 const Contact(
     fullName: 'Belen Serrano',
     email:'belen.serrano@example.com '
  )
```

];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the code, there are some widgets that are not available.

```
    class ContactsPage extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
              title: new Text("Contacts"),
            ),
            body: new ContactList(kContacts));
      }
    }

    const kContacts = const <Contact>[
      const Contact(
          fullName: 'Romain Hoogmoed', email: 'romain.hoogmoed@example.com'),
      const Contact(fullName: 'Emilie Olsen', email: 'emilie.olsen@example.com')
    ];

    class ContactList extends StatelessWidget {
      final List<Contact> _contacts;

      ContactList(this._contacts);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new ListView.builder(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return new _ContactListItem(_contacts[index]);
          },
          itemCount: _contacts.length,
        );
      }
    }

    class _ContactListItem extends ListTile {
      _ContactListItem(Contact contact)
          : super(
                title: new Text(contact.fullName),
                subtitle: new Text(contact.email),
                leading: new CircleAvatar(child: new Text(contact.fullName[0])));
    }

    class Contact {
      final String fullName;
      final String email;

      const Contact({this.fullName, this.email});
    }
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, it does work. Just wondering, is it possible to import contact data from contact data page?

Comment: what do you mean? import contacts from your contact list in your device?

Comment: Sorry, I mean I have made a contacts data page which stores all of the contacts information, and I want to import that information to ContactPage, instead of them being stored in ContactPage. I will add contacts data page to original post.

Comment: yes, it's possible, do you want to store in memory or using database to persist data?

Comment: Memory for now.

Comment: yes, import your import 'package:your_project_name/contacts_data.dart';  and use  kContacts var ,  remove the Contact class duplicate.  let me know if it works

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure where the var goes.

Comment: update your question with your code updated, you can use the kContacts when you need, but you have to import your class : import 'package:your_project_name/contacts_data.dart'  , replace with your project name

Comment: So the only thing I have updated is the import statement. Im not sure where the var goes in the code. Code is the same as above

Comment: I don't understand , why don't you use this : body: new ContactList(kContacts));   ?   kContacts is your var imported from your class contacts_data.dart

Comment: Ahhh Sorry, I was just had a mind blank, it does import data from contacts_data page.